# Фон текста в OpenCv

Tags: python, opencv

Есть картинка , которая каждые 3 секунды меняется . Берётся определённая зона и обводиться квадратом .Чуть выше квадрата выводиться текст. Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать фон текста как в этом примере?

Comment: Смотри cv::getTextSize

Comment: А нету встроенной команды opencv что бы цвет фоновый сделать для текста?

Comment: Как вы понимаете "фон текста" - залить прямоугольник в котором выводится текст цветом или нечто другое?

Comment: Да , так тоже можно

Comment: Вы можете уточнить формулировку вопроса? Вам надо вывести текст на пустую (или однородно залитую) картинку (как в ответе @jfs) или вывести текст на существующую картинку (как у меня в ответе) или что-то еще?

Comment: @MaxU хорошо , сейчас изменю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример: полупрозрачный прямоугольник в качестве фона для текста:

```
import cv2

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/samples/data/lena.jpg'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
ret,img = cap.read()
#sav = img.copy()    

#img = sav.copy()
overlay = img.copy()

font = cv2.LINE_AA
fontScale = 1
label = 'lena.jpg'
thickness = 2
text_color = (77,77,77)
text_width, text_height = cv2.getTextSize(label, font, fontScale, thickness)
text_coord = (5,text_height+20)

cv2.rectangle(overlay, 
              (text_coord[0]-5, text_coord[1]+text_height),
              (text_width[0]+10, 0),
              (0, 255, 0),
              -1)
opacity = 0.25
cv2.addWeighted(overlay, opacity, img, 1 - opacity, 0, img)

cv2.putText(img, label, text_coord, font, fontScale, text_color,thickness)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.imwrite(r'd:/temp/lena_result.jpg', img)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: размеры прямоугольника под текст, [можно с помощью `getTextSize()` узнать](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#gettextsize).

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, сейчас добавлю

Comment: `text_width, text_height` в заблуждение вводит. Возвращаемое значение у `getTextSize()` другую форму имеет: `[(width, height), baseline]`

Comment: А текст рисуется на img поверх overlay, чтобы текст не стал прозрачным?

Comment: @gil9red, текст рисуется после смешивания с `overlay` (`cv2.addWeighted()`), чтобы не изменять цвет самого текста

Answer (score 1):

Выводя текст фон не затирается—что там было, то и остаётся. Поэтому, чтобы вывести текст на чёрном фоне, достаточно текст нарисовать на чёрной картинке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import cv2

text = 'OpenCV'
img = np.zeros((300, 800, 3), np.uint8)  # black image
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
scale = 6
color = (0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d)
thickness = 20
position = (10, 200)
cv2.putText(img, text, position, font, scale, color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite('text-on-black.png', img)
```

[image: text on black]

Используя [`getTextSize()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga3d2abfcb995fd2db908c8288199dba82), можно под самим текстом фон изменить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import cv2  # $ pip install opencv-python

text = 'OpenCV'
img_color = (0x4d, 0x1c, 0x33)
text_bg_color = (0x1c, 0x4b, 0x4d)
baseline_color = (0x4d, 0x36, 0x1c)
text_color = (0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
scale = 6
thickness = 20
[(width, height), baseline] = cv2.getTextSize(text, font, scale, thickness)

# image filled with color
img = np.full((300, 800, 3), img_color, dtype=np.uint8)

# center the text
w = (img.shape[1] - width + thickness) // 2
h = (img.shape[0] + height - baseline) // 2

# draw the box
cv2.rectangle(img, (w, h + baseline), (w + width - thickness, h - height),
              text_bg_color, cv2.FILLED)
# the baseline
cv2.line(img, (w, h + thickness), (w + width - thickness, h + thickness),
         baseline_color, thickness)
# the text itself
cv2.putText(img, text, (w, h), font, scale, text_color, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite('text-on-colored-background.png', img)
```

[image: text on colored background]

Comment: я не совсем понял как это отвечает на вопрос... А если не черный фон?

Comment: @MaxU: фон естественно любого цвета может быть. К примеру: `img[:] = (100, 255, 100)`

Comment: Я не понял как наложить текст с фоном на _существующую_ картинку как у меня в ответе? Используя ваш метод...

Comment: @MaxU: вы прочитайте текст в *моём ответе* и прочитайте заголовок вопроса, по которому сюда люди из гугла могут прийти. Ваша интерпретация также подходит, но она не единственно возможная. Иногда простой вариант как у меня в ответе больше может подходить.

Comment: может быть... давайте подождем что скажет автор вопроса...

Comment: @MaxU: ещё раз: 1- обратите внимание на отсутствие слов: "существующая картинка" в вопросе  2- ответы на Stack Overflow не  только и не столько для автора вопроса существуют¶ Иначе совсем другие ответы нужно было бы давать. К примеру, вместо того чтобы на элементарные вопросы отвечать, на других форумах, можно было бы автора поучить гуглом пользоваться. На Stack Overflow так не следует поступать (следует прямой ответ дать на вопрос как он поставлен, возможно с оговорками). "Давайте подождем что скажут" посетители из гугла.

Comment: я не вижу смысла указывать фон текста на пустой (или однородно-закрашенной) картинке - вся картинка и будет фоном. Я пользовался исключительно логикой, а не текущей формулировкой вопроса. Я кстати уже почти ее изменил, но потом заметил ваш ответ и решил не менять, чтобы не иннвалидировать ваш ответ.

Comment: @MaxU: вы может и не видите смысла, это не значит, что  у людей не может быть задачи нарисовать текст на заданном фоне, используя opencv. И они могут в гугл вбить: "фон текста в opencv"